# What does the Settings > Accessibility > Automate setting do on Android?

Tags: android

I can't find documentation for this setting anywhere and I'm not sure which versions it has been included with.

What does this accessibility toggle change/enable specifically?

Comment: I misunderstood how AccessibilityServices were implemented on Android systems. The toggle enables/disables the ability to start/stop a preregistered accessibility service that has been installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood how AccessibilityServices were implemented on Android systems. The toggle enables/disables the ability to start/stop a preregistered accessibility service that has been installed.

The one named "Automate" was installed by the Automate app I downloaded from Android store.